# Image Processing: how to imwarp with mask on destination

Tags: python, image, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I want to implement a function similar to Matlab's imwarp

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

```
function [output] = maskedImwarp(im, tform, mask)
    ???
end
```

so that it will do the same as imwarp (for projective2d is enough, no need for any extras), but will only calculate for the ROI defined by mask.

I want to reduce the runtime by doing less calculations.

How can this be done in the most efficient and elegant way?

I would just do a for loop on every '1' in the mask, and calculate where it came from in 'im', and then interpolate, but I think it would be much slower than possible if I used some matrix magic.

Comment: Doesn't OpenCVs' `cv::warpAffine` or `cv::Transform` gets you expected output ?

Comment: No. It does not allow for a mask. Also, I much prefer it being in matlab.

Comment: You can apply the mask after warping ?

Comment: No, i need to save runtime. Must apply mask before interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV and Matlab do not offer a mask for image warping, I think partly because it isn't completely clear what would happen in certain cases. For example, consider an image that was something like

```
170 200 120
100 230 200
70  120 20
```

with mask

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

What is exactly supposed to happen once you transform? Do you interpolate over the hole? Or do you leave it as black? If you transform to a smaller size and that hole after interpolation closes up, do you force it in again? It just seems like it could easily produce unintended consequences and so it's weird to deal with, and doesn't really make sense to force someone's hand here.

Of course, you're probably looking more to have an inclusive region that wouldn't have holes; e.g. a mask like

```
0 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
```

or something, but even then, it could be weird. Rotations for example happen around the origin, but if your mask ignores the first couple rows and columns, it's not exactly clear if someone would want that transformation to be in reference to the whole original image or in reference to where the mask starts.

I can easily see the use case for masks, but I don't think you'll see it implemented in most libraries because there's no real clear right way to do it, each use case would be different. Not impossible to implement with some flags or anything of course, but there's probably just not a huge need to try and deal with those possibilities.

Anyways, I see three ways of doing this.

1. Filter out the colored mask regions after warping.
2. Warping the inverse mask locations themselves and the removing everything from the warped image where those pixels were moved to.
3. Get the indices with `meshgrid` and then only apply the warp to the masked indices of `meshgrid` and interpolate the masked image on top of just those points. I have no idea if this is possible to implement with built-in functions though since you cannot reasonably create a 2-D masked image with a non-rectangular mask without inserting junk values. So it looks like you might have to loop through to interpolate.

Comment: My roi is actually very small compared to the image. The point was to save runtime, not to do post processing

Comment: @Gulzar I see. Then yeah, I'd go with the third method. Let me see if I can modify some of my prior code to make this work.

Comment: @Gulzar hmm, this is difficult. There is no way to specify a mask for interpolation for the same reasons mentioned above, and you cannot use `interp2` for a 1-D (i.e. masked image) vector, and there's no way to apply a mask and return a 2-D image unless the mask is exactly rectangular. How oblong is your mask? It would still reduce computation time to take the bounding rectangle of your mask, and then post process to remove what isn't masked.

Comment: Yeah, this seems very difficult for vectorization with none of the snappy functions providing support here. [This discussion on Matlab central](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/235877) discusses some of the difficulties here using `interp2` for this. I can't think of anything outside of looping through without the support from functions that make these operations fast in the first place. Hope someone else can chime in with something a bit more brilliant.

Comment: Coming back here 4 years later, I wonder if something new exists to answer this problem? I need a reverse mapping from a mask to a texture. The mask is not rectangular, but it is defined by 4 corners. Surely SOMETHING smarter than reverse-warping the entire destination image can be done?