# Image Processing: how to imwarp with simple mask on destination?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Following [my own question from 4 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919279/image-processing-how-to-imwarp-with-mask-on-destination), this time in Python only-

I am looking for a way to perform texture mapping into a small region in a destination image, defined by 4 corners given as (x, y) pixel coordinates. This region is not necessarily rectangular. It is a perspective projection of some rectangle onto the image plane.

I would like to map some (rectangular) texture into the mask defined by those corners.

---

Mapping directly by forward-mapping the texture [will not work properly](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Forward-and-backward-image-warping-In-the-case-of-foward-warping-A-holes-can-occur_fig2_267946997), as source pixels will be mapped to non-integer locations in the destination.

This problem is usually solved by inverse-warping from the destination to the source, then coloring according to some interpolation.

Opencv's [`warpPerspective`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) doesn't work here, as it can't take a mask in.

Inverse-warping the entire destination and then mask is not acceptable because the majority of the computation is redundant.

---

1. Is there a built-in opencv (or other) function that accomplishes above requirements?
2. If not, what is a good way to get a list of pixels from my ROI defined by corners, in favor of passing that to [`projectPoints`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d9/d0c)?

---

Example background image:

[image]

I want to fill the area outlined by the red lines (defined by its corners) with some other texture, say this one

[image]

Mapping between them can be obtained by mapping the texture's corners to the ROI corners with `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform`

Comment: Can you post an example image and identify the region you want to warp and how it should be warped. A picture would help understand and provide an image to use to demonstrate. There is no built in function that I know for masking.

Comment: @fmw42 added an example, I hope it is clearer now

Comment: I'd recommend using OpenGL or some other 3D graphics API for this.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz 1. this has nothing to do with 3d. 2. Can you please provide a code example of how to efficiently accomplish this using any Python tool or library?

Comment: I still think you'll be happier with a 3D API. do you think those can't be used from python? I have a simple idea that uses only OpenCV and numpy, but you might not like it because it's not perfectly efficient.  you seem to find execution speed important

Comment: I would create a small image with size of the bounding box around the mask zone, then use warpPerspective followed by .copyTo with the actual mask.

Comment: you said "texture mapping". you know this is a graphics problem and OpenCV isn't a graphics library, but a vision library. OpenGL/D3D/Vulkan don't have to involve 3D but they do give you the ability to draw triangles and textures. a perspective warp is precisely a 3D plane-to-plane mapping. I see no reason why you shouldn't use those facilities.

Comment: I do not think you would be saving anything since the input image is all warped to a small area in the output. So if you could just warp and insert it would be about the same computations as warping to a small image and then inserting, because the insert process is more complicated in the latter case. Going the other way from a small section of input to the full output could save by warping only the small section.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Like I said, I don't mind using other libraries, and will appreciate a code example of how to do that.

Comment: @fmw42 [forward warping creates artifacts](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Forward-and-backward-image-warping-In-the-case-of-foward-warping-A-holes-can-occur_fig2_267946997), thus is unacceptable. I do want to only warp the small section - question is how, technically, with code, to do that. I couldn't do it myself...

Comment: @Micka this is so far the best suggestion, but still is inefficient (~x2 caclulation).

Comment: most efficient is probably to use vertices and texture from openGL/GLSL or similar, but depending on the implementation, copying images to the gpu might be an overkill. In addition, learning the api/library might take a lot pf development time. Doing the inverse warping manually is quite simple, but very probably the implementation might be much less efficient than using the ROI way with highly optimized opencv code in most of the common situations, in practice.

Comment: @Micka Thanks, this is why I ask on Stackoverflow for a simple implementation or at least a reference to the relevant API methods.

Comment: I could share the manual inverse warping and the ROI way, but dont have time. For the opengl way I only know the theory but maybe this one helps: https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures

Comment: I was not suggesting forward warping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future generations, here is how to only back and forward warp pixels within the bbox of the warped corner points, as @Micka suggested.

here `banner` is the grass image, and `banner_coords_2d` are the corners of the red region on `image`, which is meme-man.

```
def transform_banner(banner_coords_2d, banner, image):
    # show_points_on_image("banner corners", image, banner_coords_2d)

    banner_height, banner_width, _ = banner.shape
    src_banner_points = np.float32([
        [0, 0],
        [banner_width - 1, 0],
        [0, banner_height - 1],
        [banner_width - 1, banner_height - 1],
    ])

    # only warp to size of bbox of warped corners, not all of the image
    warped_left = np.round(np.min(banner_coords_2d[:, 0])).astype(int)
    warped_right = np.round(np.max(banner_coords_2d[:, 0])).astype(int)
    warped_top = np.round(np.min(banner_coords_2d[:, 1])).astype(int)
    warped_bottom = np.round(np.max(banner_coords_2d[:, 1])).astype(int)
    warped_width = int(warped_right - warped_left)
    warped_height = int(warped_bottom - warped_top)

    dst_banner_points = banner_coords_2d.astype(np.float32)
    dst_banner_points[:, 0] -= warped_left
    dst_banner_points[:, 1] -= warped_top

    tform = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src_banner_points, dst_banner_points)

    warped_banner = cv2.warpPerspective(banner, tform, (warped_width, warped_height))
    # cv2.imshow("warped_banner", warped_banner)
    image_with_banner = image.copy()
    image_with_banner[warped_top: warped_bottom, warped_left: warped_right][warped_banner != 0] = warped_banner[
        warped_banner != 0]
    # cv2.imshow("image_with_banner", image_with_banner)

    return image_with_banner
```

Likely, this can be done more neatly, I am open to edits.